# Jqueryui dialog("close") ends current javascript thread

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Hi I am having an issue with closing my jquery dialog.
What I have is a comet connection that sends messages to my browser. What I would like to do is when I receive a message I want to do some stuff, close the dialog then do some more stuff. Unfortunately when I execute: $('#dialog').dialog("close"); It ends my current javascript code. Is there a way to avoid this? or do I need to make sure the close is run right at the end using a variable?

For example, here you can see that my text will not change when it is after:
http://jsfiddle.net/hKhMC/

This is a simple demonstration my actual code does a lot of calculations afterwards so I was wondering if there was a solution that doesn't involve moving the text before the close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are recursively firing the dialog close event.  In Chrome your jsfiddle example causes a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.  This is because the  `.dialog('close')` method fires the `dialogclose` event after closing the dialog. This event is also fired when someone clicks the `X` button on the dialog toolbar or presses the `ESC` key.

However you are binding this event during the dialog initialization and then calling the same method that can trigger it again.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution to my problem.

Below was the code used to create the JQueryUI dialog

```
$('#currentCallDialog').dialog({
    autoOpen : false,
    height : 350,
    width : 550,
    modal : true,
    buttons : {
        "Open" : function() {
            //.. Do something
        }
    },
    close : function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
});
```

the problem is in the close button i try to call dialog("close"); Once this was removed it all worked fine, please see below code for working example:

```
$('#currentCallDialog').dialog({
    autoOpen : false,
    height : 350,
    width : 550,
    modal : true,
    buttons : {
        "Open" : function() {
            //.. Do something
        }
    },
    close : function() {
        //.. Do something
    }
});
```